# Tidymodels xgboost using step_dummy(one_hot =T) - set mtry as proportion instead of range when creating custom grid and tuning with tune_race_anova

Tags: r, xgboost, tidymodels

My train data has 32 columns, but since I am incorporating step_dummy(all_nomical_predictors), one_hot = T) in my recipe, I end up with more than 32 columns when modeling. Therefore, just running finalize(mtry, select(data_train, -outcome)) gives me values for mtry's upper range that are too low.

How do I go about handling mtry as a proportion of variables instead of count? I need to be able to create a custom grid (where I set the range of the proportion) and I will be running tune_race_anova. This is my code (after running the recipe):

```
 xgb_spec <- 
   boost_tree(
              tree_depth = tune(),
              trees = 500,
              learn_rate = tune(),
              loss_reduction = tune(),
              sample_size = tune(),
              stop_iter = tune(),
              mtry = tune(),
              min_n = tune()
              ) %>% 
   set_engine("xgboost", validation = 0.2, counts = FALSE) %>% 
   set_mode("regression") 

# Normally I have several workflows
xgb_workflows <- 
  workflowsets::workflow_set(
    preproc = list(recipe_xg),
    models = list(xgboost = xgb_spec),
    cross = TRUE
  )

# Custom grid
grid_xgb <- 
  grid_latin_hypercube(
    learn_rate(),
    min_n(),
    mtry(range = c(0.3, 1.0), 
    sample_size = sample_prop(),
    tree_depth(),
    loss_reduction(),
    stop_iter(),
    size = 30
  )
```

This, however, does not work. When I run my tuning code:

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(parallel::detectCores(logical = FALSE))
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = cl-1)

race_ctrl <-
   control_race(
      save_pred = F,
      parallel_over = "everything",
      save_workflow = F
   )

start_time <- Sys.time()

race_results <-
   xgb_workflows %>%
   workflow_map(
      "tune_race_anova",
      seed = 1503,
      resamples = train_folds,
      grid = grid_xgb, 
      control = race_ctrl
   )

end_time <- Sys.time()
training_time <- end_time-start_time
```

I get error messages. What am I missing to properly include mtry as a proportion in my custom grind instead of having to set a count manually. Another workaround would be able to set the upper count of ncols in my training data AFTER onehot encoding has been carried out.

However, proportion would still be better, since I also have another scenario where I loop through various different numbers of predictors and therefore proportion would just be easier (instead of having to update every single mtry value for each workflow in the workflowsets).

Comment: You can `extract_parameter_set_dials()` from your workflow and then `finalize(training_df)` to get the number of vars after pre-processing steps. There's an example in the Tidy Modeling with R book ([Ch12](https://www.tmwr.org/tuning#tuning-params-tidymodels))